# Efficient way to compute the ninth order Maclaurin polynomial of $\sin(\arctan(x^2))$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, substitution

Substitution is a favourite of mine but this really gives me an headache. We had a discussion in class about the Maclaurin evaluation up to degree 9 on this function:

$$f(x) = \sin(\arctan(x^2))$$

There are endless possibilities. What would be your best shot?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: How would you solve it?

Comment: Solve what? I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is to find the Maclaurin Series Expansion to degree 9 for the function. Sorry if I'm not very good at explaining.

Comment: Edited: grade $\ne $ degree.

Comment: @Terry  If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi Sure! If possible, can you show the first step of the composition?

Comment: @Terry I've just plugged into the expansion for $\sin t$ for $t\to0$ the expansion for $\arctan x^2\to0$

Comment: @Terry I've edited the answer in order to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simply to **compose the expansions**

$$\arctan x = x -\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^{\frac92})$$

$$\arctan x^2 =x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}+o(x^9)$$

$$\sin t = t -\frac{t^3}{6}+o(t^3)$$

Thus for $t= \arctan x^2 =x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}+o(x^9)$

$$\sin (\arctan x^2) = x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}-\frac16\left(x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}\right)^3+o(x^9)=\\=x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}-\frac{x^6}{6}+o(x^9)=x^2 -\frac{x^6}{2}+o(x^9)$$

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Will bring this to my friends.

Comment: @gimusi I think you have a typo in your second last line; you've got $\sin\arctan x$ on the LHS but $\sin\arctan x^2$ on the RHS

Comment: ops yes of course, just a typo thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $$\sin(\arctan(x^2))=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}},$$ using elementary trigonometric identities. Then use the binomial expansion
$$(1+x^4)^{-1/2}=1+\binom{-1/2}{1}x^4+\binom{-1/2}{2}x^8+\ldots$$

Comment: How would you decide to continue? I get stuck in long-step evaluations for degree 9.